SQL Server Log shipping do not work for multiple databases inside T-SQL loop
I want to set SQL Server log shipping for all databases on a server. When I configure database (on master side) one by one, there is no problem.
Problem occurs when put configuration ( for master side ) inside loop to try set up databases automatically. When this loop is finished I can see job created only for last database

however there are 2 databases on server

Seems be that last configured database inside loop overwrites job from previous database so that on the end there is only one job (from last database).
At the same time I can see log shipping misconfiguration on all databases except the last one and info that specific job doesn't exist. Text is here:
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

The current log shipping configuration is not functional because the required backup job cannot be found. You must drop the current configuration by clearing the 'Enable this as a primary database in a log shipping configuration' checkbox. To resume log shipping, recreate the configuration using the same settings.

If you resume log shipping and you specify the backup and restore paths that you used before, any backup files from the old configuration that are uncopied or unrestored will be copied and restored by the new configuration.  Reinitializing the secondary databases is unnecessary.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The specified @job_id ('6A310814-0FEF-4C10-A738-4BBEB2BC2CEE') does not exist. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14262)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-14262-database-engine-error


My script for automatic setup of log shipping for all databases is here:
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(256) -- database name  
 
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.sys.databases AS sysdb
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.log_shipping_primary_databases AS log_shipping ON sysdb.name = log_shipping.primary_database
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  -- exclude these databases
AND state = 0 -- database is online
AND is_in_standby = 0 -- database is not read only for log shipping
and log_shipping.primary_database is null
 
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   

    DECLARE @LS_BackupJobId AS uniqueidentifier 
    DECLARE @LS_PrimaryId   AS uniqueidentifier 
    DECLARE @SP_Add_RetCode As int 

    DECLARE @databaseName NVARCHAR(200);
    SET @databaseName = N''+ @name + '';

    DECLARE @backupString NVARCHAR(20);
    SET @backupString = N'LSBackup_' + @databaseName;

    EXEC @SP_Add_RetCode = master.dbo.sp_add_log_shipping_primary_database 
        @database = @databaseName
        ,@backup_directory = N'/var/opt/mssql/shipping' 
        ,@backup_share = N'/var/opt/mssql/shipping' 
        ,@backup_job_name = @backupString
        ,@backup_retention_period = 360
        ,@backup_threshold = 60 
        ,@threshold_alert_enabled = 1
        ,@history_retention_period = 5760 
        ,@backup_job_id = @LS_BackupJobId OUTPUT 
        ,@primary_id = @LS_PrimaryId OUTPUT 
        ,@overwrite = 1 

    IF (@@ERROR = 0 AND @SP_Add_RetCode = 0) 
    BEGIN 

        
        DECLARE @LS_BackUpScheduleUID   As uniqueidentifier 
        DECLARE @LS_BackUpScheduleID    AS int 
                

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule 
            @schedule_name =N'LSBackupSchedule_172.11.12.101' 
            ,@enabled = 1 
            ,@freq_type = 4 
            ,@freq_interval = 1 
            ,@freq_subday_type = 4 
            ,@freq_subday_interval = 15 
            ,@freq_recurrence_factor = 0 
            ,@active_start_date = 20241112 
            ,@active_end_date = 99991231 
            ,@active_start_time = 0 
            ,@active_end_time = 235900 
            ,@schedule_uid = @LS_BackUpScheduleUID OUTPUT 
            ,@schedule_id = @LS_BackUpScheduleID OUTPUT


        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule 
            @job_id = @LS_BackupJobId 
            ,@schedule_id = @LS_BackUpScheduleID  

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job 
            @job_id = @LS_BackupJobId 
            ,@enabled = 0 

    END 

    EXEC master.dbo.sp_add_log_shipping_alert_job 

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   
 
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor


How should I modify this script in order to create successfully backup job for every database ? Any help welcomed.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

sql server doesn't reset variables to null on de-declare inside loops, probably what you need is to set all variables to explicite = NULL inside the loops, especially those related to jobIds

Why log shipping instead of eg basic availability groups? Log shipping isn't just old, it's so old its replacement (database mirroring) got replaced (by AGs) 12 years ago

@PanagiotisKanavos - imo, neither Mirroring nor AGs are a direct replacement for log shipping. LS provides the ability to delay restores (for "oops, I dropped a table in production" moments), restore to a provided point in time, etc. Moreover, while I can find a deprecation notice for Mirroring, I can't for LS. Do you have one handy?

@siggemannen Thank you, you solved my problem. It works !

@PanagiotisKanavos Log shipping because our project has dedicated only SQL Server Web Edition and this edition can only with log shipping works.
